# Getting supported pixel formats from QCamera on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is there a way to get a list of supported pixel formats (RGB24, RGB32, etc.) of a connected camera using Qt (5.6.2) on Windows?

I am currently capturing frames using QCameraImageCapture (initialized with my USB webcam).

I have tried calling QCameraImageCapture::supportedBufferFormats() but always receive an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QCamera::supportedViewfinderPixelFormats()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html#supportedViewfinderPixelFormats), to get a list of supported by QCamera formats.

But note, QCamera can provide only frames in RGB32 to its surface on Windows, due to current implementation limitation.